# Static html web page in maven

Tags: html, maven, static

I want to have static html web page as an maven project. I have done project like advised on this tutorial http://www.doclo.be/lieven/articles/personalsitewithmaven.html.

I have copyied my static html web page with complete structure into src/site/resources directory and I have deleted all files/directories in src/site directory (instead of resources dir).

I have added into pom.xml file in reporting section plugin called maven-linkcheck-plugin (its usage is described on http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-linkcheck-plugin/usage.html).

I want to have something like surefire plugin in project which will fail build if there will be any error in links on generated web page. linkcheck plugin seems to check just validity of links and tryies to retrieve head of all links. It does not generate any error when referencing nonexisting pdf file for example.

To have my project, just do this:

```
mvn archetype:create -DgroupId=com.mypage -DartifactId=mypage -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-site-simple
cd mypage
rm -r src/site/*
mkdir src/site/resources
echo "<h1>my last web page, I promisse</h1> <a href="relativeUrlToNonexistentPage.html">Link text</a>" > src/site/resources/index.html
```

Than edit pom.xml and add there:

```
  <reporting>
   <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.7</version>
     <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
           <reports />
          </reportSet>
     </reportSets>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-linkcheck-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <excludedLinks>
            <excludedLink>https://trackit.sk/app</excludedLink>
          </excludedLinks>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Than just run:
    mvn clean site:run
and than open http:// localhost:8080 web page. There you will see link which is nor working.

When I run:
    mvn clean linkcheck:linkcheck
there is in target directory generated report, but no error. According the report it seems that invalid url link was not scanned.

I want to check all ulrs (all relative will be enough) by some maven plugin. Is there any possibility to do that by linkcheck plugin, or I should use for this thing some other plugin?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can for example create a warfile (web app) with Maven that contains just plain HTML files.

Just set `packaging` to `war` and drop plain HTML files in `src/main/webapp`

When you copy `yourprojectname.war` into a tomcat `webapps` folder on your computer and one of those files is for example called `example.html`, the URL to that file could for example be `http://localhost:8080/yourprojectname/example.html`.

Please refer to [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) and [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/) documenations for details.

Answer (score -3):

First of all maven is a repository system for libraries and is based on project object model i.e. POM and we add dependencies in pom.xml so that maven should automatically download all the libraries that your project requires. Your question is that you want to save static html page as maven project but maven is nothing to with that page its up to your ide how to manage your static resources so check out the documentation for your IDE

Comment: I see maven as an project (any project) configuration thing. I use Jenkins to build all my projects (dynamic web pages, android applications, java applications, erlang servers, etc). Why not build AND test also my simple, static, web page? I accept that it is a little bit too easy project type for maven, but what other tool to use?

Comment: you can use eclipse or MyEclipse or NetBeans whatever you want you can use also refer http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/maven-tutorials for more details

Comment: Maven is not only a library manager. It's a project configuration helper that allows you to build, test, configure, filter, generate help site, deploy, do coffee... You can create "pom" module in your Maven structure (which will generate pom and not jar or war). So, there is no reason not to use Maven for a HTML static pages project, mainly if this project is used as an independant front-end in a SOA purpose.

Comment: can you provide more details over it.